# How to TakeWhile not zero of functions?

Tags: functions

```
fuu[x_]:= 2 - x^3 + x^7
```

This works:

```
TakeWhile[{5, 4, 3, 2, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0}, # != 0 &]
(*{5, 4, 3, 2, 2, 1}*)
```

This doesn't:

```
Table[D[fuu[x], {x, n}], {n, 0, 10}]
(*{2 - x^3 + x^7, -3 x^2 + 7 x^6, -6 x + 42 x^5, -6 + 210 x^4, 840 x^3, 
 2520 x^2, 5040 x, 5040, 0, 0, 0}*)

TakeWhile[%, #1 != 0 &]
(*{}*)
```

Comment: Please include `fuu` in your question so that it's self contained.

Comment: i did it thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mathematica cannot evaluate an expression with an undefined variable as (`Not`)`Equal` to `0`; however, it can evaluate the expression as (`Not`)`SameQ` to `0`

```
{2 - x^3 + x^7 == 0, 2 - x^3 + x^7 != 0, 
 2 - x^3 + x^7 === 0, ! (2 - x^3 + x^7 === 0)}
```

> {2 - x^3 + x^7 == 0,     2 - x^3 + x^7 != 0, False, True}

```
fuu[x_] = 2 - x^3 + x^7;

Table[D[fuu[x], {x, n}], {n, 0, 10}]
```

> {2 - x^3 + x^7, -3*x^2 + 7*x^6,     -6*x + 42*x^5, -6 + 210*x^4,
>   840*x^3, 2520*x^2, 5040*x,     5040, 0, 0, 0}

```
TakeWhile[%, ! (# === 0) &]
```

> {2 - x^3 + x^7, -3*x^2 + 7*x^6,     -6*x + 42*x^5, -6 + 210*x^4,
>   840*x^3, 2520*x^2, 5040*x, 5040}

Comment: Shorter: `# =!= 0 &`.

Comment: @Guesswhoitis. - Thanks.

Comment: Thanks a lot to both of you. I tried it with SameQ.. and a lot of variations of ! === ^^ but in the wrong way